# kubernetes examples document link

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How does the URL path of the k8's examples can be browsed?

If you look at the below example, I can run a pod with storage as shown below.

E.g.: kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml

But if I just browse the path - https://k8s.io/examples or https://k8s.io/examples/pods it gives me a HTTP 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you look at the below example, I can run a pod with storage as shown
> below.
>
> E.g.: kubectl apply -f
> https://k8s.io/examples/pods/storage/pv-volume.yaml

Its here https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/master/content/en/examples/pods/storage/pv-pod.yaml

So basically

**1.** All examples from [Tasks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/) page: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/tree/master/content/en/examples

**2.** Different application, used in docs: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/tree/master/content/en/examples/application

Also you can take a look into [k8smeetup/old_k8sdoc](https://github.com/k8smeetup/old_k8sdoc/tree/main/docs/tasks) github page, eg [job.yaml](https://github.com/k8smeetup/old_k8sdoc/blob/main/docs/tasks/job/job.yaml)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the task for practice. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/